# Can the device seed be recovered from the iPhone/Android RSA SecurID app?

Tags: authentication, rsa

The Windows RSA SecurID app allows the device seed to be determined and cloned from one machine to another (see this [blog post](http://www.sensepost.com/blog/7045.html)).

Do either the iPhone or Android RSA SecurID apps suffer from the same issue?